# PyQt5 QGraphicsView segfaults on application close

Tags: python, qt, segmentation-fault, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having a little bit of an odd issue.  I recently ported my application from PyQt4 to PyQt5.  The source code here will run fine, but when you close the application it will segfault.  The issue seems to arise when you set the QGraphicsView to have a scene.  If I took away the scene, there would be no issues.  Yet even if there was an empty scene there would be a segfault.

```
# A simple example to implement a layer feature, it tests:
# -- Layers
# -- .gif load and aniamiton
# -- Zooming
#
# All if this should be done using the QGraphicsView Framework

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# TODO, this is now segfaulting because of update to PyQt5, fix it


class LayerWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LayerWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Some Varibales
        self.scale = 2
        self.viewSize = QSize()         # Size we want for the view at all times

        # Get the scene
        self.scene = LayerScene(self)

        # Set the view
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)              # Doesn't segfault if a scene is not set
        self.view.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.view.scale(self.scale, self.scale)

        self.viewSize = self.scene.sceneRect().toRect().size() * self.scale

        # Other
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple Layers Test (w/ Animation)')
        self.resize(self.viewSize)


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Try to keep the view in the center of the window at all times
        widgetSize = self.size()
        viewSize = self.viewSize

        # Check the sizes
        widgetWidthSmaller = widgetSize.width() < viewSize.width()
        widgetHeightSmaller = widgetSize.height() < viewSize.height()
        if widgetWidthSmaller or widgetHeightSmaller:
            # too small, resize the view

            # Make the new sized view
            newSize = QSize()
            newSize.setWidth(widgetSize.width() if widgetWidthSmaller else viewSize.width())
            newSize.setHeight(widgetSize.height() if widgetHeightSmaller else viewSize.height())

            newLoc = QPoint()
            newLoc.setX(0 if widgetWidthSmaller else self.view.pos().x())
            newLoc.setY(0 if widgetHeightSmaller else self.view.pos().y())

            # Change the minimum size and resize the view
            self.view.resize(newSize)
            self.view.move(newLoc)
        else:
            # No scrolly-bars
            self.view.resize(self.viewSize)

            # Keep it centered
            viewRect = self.view.rect()
            viewRect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
            self.view.move(viewRect.topLeft())




class LayerScene(QGraphicsScene):
    # Represents a "frame," with multiple layers  

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LayerScene, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layer = []

        # Hard code in some images
        self.layer.append(QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage('orange_glow.png'))))
        self.layer.append(AnimatedGIF('blue_spirit.gif'))

        self.layer[1].moveBy(50, 50)

        self.addItem(self.layer[0])
        self.addItem(self.layer[1])

        self.layer[1].start()




class AnimatedGIF(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    # A small test of an animated gif playing in a graphics scene

    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        super(AnimatedGIF, self).__init__(parent)

        self.gif = QMovie(filename)
        self.gif.frameChanged[int].connect(self.nextFrame)


    def nextFrame(self, n):
        self.setPixmap(self.gif.currentPixmap())


    def start(self):
        self.gif.start()



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    lw = LayerWidget()
    lw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

I have another app that uses two scenes and graphics views but that one doesn't segfault at all.  The only main difference is that the second app uses a QMainWindow and BoxLayout instead of QWidget as a container.

Comment: You should not resize anything inside resizeEvent. It can lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: I understand that, but it's not resizing the widget itself, but a child widget.  What do you recommend doing instead?